# What is the reason for checking for nullity twice when synchronizing lazy initialization?

Tags: java, concurrency, lazy-initialization

I came across a lazy initialization method which checks for nullity twice, before and after applying the lock. Code goes like this,

```
public void initializeTemplate(){
   if(tmeplate == null){
      synchronized(this){
         if(template == null){
              //initialization is done here!
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I was wondering what could be the reason behind checking for nullity twice? In my understanding checking before applying the lock would have sufficed, right? or am i wrong? Can anyone explain?

Comment: A `null` check is cheap, where as `synchronized` is not, BUT, some other thread might have beaten you to the initialisation of the object between the first `null` check and the `synchronized` block, so you check once out side (cheap) and once instead as a precaution.

Comment: This is basically trapping a race condition, where two threads pass through the outer check, one thread will block waiting for the `synchronized` block to provide it the lock, while the other passes through (having secured the lock), creating an instance of the object and assigning the value to `template`.  When it exists, the waiting thread will then have a chance to execute the code within the `synchronized` block, but you do a second `null` check to make sure you're not doing work which has already been done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `null` check is cheap, where as `synchronized` is not, BUT, some other thread might have beaten you to the initialisation of the object between the first `null` check and the `synchronized` block, so you check once out side (cheap) and once instead as a precaution.

This is basically trapping a race condition, where two threads pass through the outer check, one thread will block waiting for the `synchronized` block to provide it the lock, while the other passes through (having secured the lock), creating an instance of the object and assigning the value to `template`.  When it exists, the waiting thread will then have a chance to execute the code within the `synchronized` block, but you do a second `null` check to make sure you're not doing work which has already been done and breaking the single instance requirements and preventing possible reference issues

Comment: So with the outer check threads can learn whether the work has already been done without waiting to obtain the lock and creating a narrow sequential path through the method, right?

Comment: @javabot Yeah pretty much, the point been is that it's cheap to do a `null` check, but obtaining a lock via the `synchronized` takes time, so if the value has already been assigned, there's no point in trying to obtain the lock and waste time ;)

Comment: Zaid has attached a link to his answer which says this won't work. But I am having doubts on the reasons the post gives for this not  working. Do you also think this does not work?

Comment: I've not really looked into the links, I do, however, understand that it's been some what discouraged in the past in favor of using a `enum` which guarantees, through the language specification, that it will only be initialized once.

Comment: I guess one of the problems might be is `template` would need to marked as `volatile` before it could guarantee (at least more so) that threads would see the same value, a better solution would be to wrap `template` in some kind of `Atomic` class, maybe something like [`AtomicReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) (but I've not used this particular class) ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is called **Double-checked locking**. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) Wikipedia article explains it in detail.

To explain it briefly, obtaining a lock is an expensive operation, in this example it is most probably used to initialize a singleton Class in a multi threaded environment.
The first if statement checks if the object is null, if the object is not null there is no need to obtain a lock to make sure that no other Thread have initialized the Object, since the object is already initialized. However, if the object is null, the Thread has to obtain a lock on the block to make sure that no other Thread is trying to initialize the Object.

The **Double-checked locking** [is considered](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) "broken".